# Jquery animate using variable not working (literal works fine)

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-animate, literals

Edit:  Solved.  I just had to call .toString on newWidthO and newWidthP.  I'd answer my question but I can't do it for 8 hours or so due to reputation stuff.

-=--------------------------------

I'm writing a simple reflex type game where the player has to click on a moving div under a time.  A bar should move to the right proportional to the player's total points compared to how many points it takes to win the game.

Here is the code:

```
var newWidthO = (((parseInt(reflexPointsAI, 10) / reflexRequiredWinPoints)*100)) + "%";
var newWidthP = (((parseInt(reflexPoints, 10) / reflexRequiredWinPoints)*100)) + "%";

$("#reflexTimer").html(newWidthO + " , " + newWidthP);

// $("#reflexOpponentScoreProgressBar").css('width', newWidthO );
//$("#reflexPlayerScoreProgressBar").css('width', newWidthP );

$("#reflexOpponentScoreProgressBar").animate( {"width" : newWidthO }, "fast" );
$("#reflexPlayerScoreProgressBar").animate( {"width" : newWidthP }, "fast" );
```

The problem I'm getting is that the animate doesn't seem to work when it should.  This operation is being called every quarter second.

If I write a literal in place of `newWidthO` or `newWidthP`, say "50%" the code animates properly, but otherwise nothing seems to happen.  The `reflexTimer` div is showing that each value is formatted properly for a CSS style sheet, like '20%', etc, so I know the values are correct.  The two lines that are commented out work fine and snap the bars to the correct places, but I'm hoping to use animate's smooth transition.

Am I missing something about how I should be formatting my animate parameters?  I've looked at other similar questions, but none seem to solve it.

Comment: Have you checked what values does newWidthO nad newwidthP have before aplying for animate.

Comment: Yes, I had in this line:  $("#reflexTimer").html(newWidthO + " , " + newWidthP);  What I needed to do was call .toString() on them because I suppose the type was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.  I hate it when my answer is so trivial.

Here's the solution:  Call .toString() for newWidthO and newWidthP.